# PHP file showing syntatical error

Tags: php, android, android-studio, server

> I'm trying to send title and content to my table named write . But i'm having error while running this php file .
>
> Below is the error shown
>
> not sucessfullyYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'write values('','','')' at line 1

```
<?php
 require "connection.php";

 $id = $_POST["id"];
 $title =$_POST["title"];
 $content =$_POST["content"];




 $sql_query ="insert into write values('$id','$title','$content');";


 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
 {
 echo"data insertion sucess";
 }
else
{
echo "not sucessfully".mysqli_error($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: As you can see there are no values. Check your form and make sure the data is posted correctly. Also, you should check if data is valid before sql query.

Comment: just echo the query and find out the actual query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WRITE` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) so you should escape it using backticks:

```
insert into `write` ...
```

But I would recommend you rename the table into something more sensible.